# Webmin server, PHP imap_open() not working properly

Tags: imap, webmin, php-imap, imap-open

My client use webmin server for using the CRM which is developed by me, in mailbox module, if user choose a email which they want to open in a mail box every thing is perfectly sometimes, if emails are listed after viewing one email some time view of email return empty content, like this randomly giving request is successfully return a IMAP value, some requests return a empty value,

but in my local machine i have Develop my application mailbox module in windows OS based machine, using xamp server, here i get a exact result for each and every request,

now i find why it's happen, the reason is in my clients webmin server couldn't open a imap stream properly, in imap_open method all arguments are real, but it return random connection failed message from imap_errors method,

i don't understand why it is happening, and also i can't fix this

So please assist me, helping hearts really appreciateable,